# analytical hierarchy and individual variable quantifiers

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability

For analytical hierarchy, $\Sigma^1_0$ is usually
defined as the class of formula that does not have
any set quantifier - but does this mean that there
can be any number of quantifiers for individual
variable?

Comment: I would caution that sometimes $\Sigma^1_0$ and $\Pi^1_0$ are used as synonyms for $\Sigma^0_1$ and $\Pi^0_1$ respectively. (This makes sense because then you can say, _e.g._ that the $\Sigma^1_1$ sets are the projections of the $\Pi^1_0$ sets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\Sigma^1_0$ and $\Pi^1_0$ formulas are exactly the arithmetical formulas, which can also be denoted $\Sigma^0_\infty$ and $\Pi^0_\infty$.  They can have any number of number quantifiers.